# Conexión con base de datos retorna null

Tags: php

Estoy usando el siguiente código para realizar una conexión a una base de datos MySQL, pero en `$r` obtengo un resultado nulo, ¿cómo podría resolverlo?

Éste es el código relevante de mi clase Meta:

```
require 'Database.php';
require 'DBOperations.php';

class Meta
{   

public static function idusu($nombre){

    $db =  new DBOperations();
    $r= $db -> getIdporNombre($nombre);


    return $r;
}
```

Así es el constructor de DBOperations:

```
public function __construct() {

    $this -> conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this -> host.";dbname=".$this -> db, $this -> user, $this -> pass);

}
```

Y así está definido el método getIdporNombre, aunque estoy seguro de que funciona bien:

```
public function getIdporNombre($nombre){

    $sql = "SELECT sno FROM users WHERE name =  ':nombre'";
    $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> execute(array('nombre' => $nombre));

    $data = $query -> fetchObject();

    return $data->sno;

}
```

Comment: This is a spanish language group, you must edit the questions or publish it in http://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés.

Comment: O también podemos traducir la pregunta, hice la edición correspondiente.

Comment: ¿Cómo defines DBOperations?¿Y cómo se llama al método `idusu`? Si el error es que `$r` es nulo, deberías de compartir también el código del constructor de DBOperations y de getIdporNombre para entender dónde está el probblema

Comment: @JoelIbaceta Has hecho más que una traducción, has cambiado el significado/esencia de la pregunta. Cierto que has convertido la pregunta al español, pero has combinado el código de dos clases diferentes (Meta y DBOperations) en una sola lo que lleva a confusiones. Ése es uno de los motivos por lo que la traducción de una pregunta debe ser hecha por la persona que pregunta y no por otros usuarios.

Comment: Si ejecutas la misma consulta en tu base de datos ¿te devuelve registros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sé que pones que estás seguro de que el método `getIdporNombre` funciona bien, pero te puedo decir que tiene al menos un error que hará que no funcione y que hará que el método devuelva `null` causando el error que ves: en la sentencia SQL, **`:nombre` no necesita ir entrecomillado porque PHP detectará si es de tipo cadena y automáticamente le pondrá las comillas**.

Una vez solucionado ese problema, el código queda así y funciona bien:

```
public function getIdporNombre($nombre){

    $sql = "SELECT sno FROM users WHERE name =  :nombre";
    $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> execute(array(':nombre' => $nombre));

    $data = $query -> fetchObject();

    return $data->sno;

}
```

Si te fijas, también he puesto el `:` antes de nombre en `execute(array(':nombre' => $nombre));`, aunque esto no es necesario para que se prepare y ejecute la sentencia correctamente (porque PDO también la añade automáticamente si no la pusiste, por eso  no lo puse como motivo), sí que sería una buena práctica ponerla por si eso cambia en el futuro.